# ASP C# Model Binding Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to validate a form using c# mvc, I have setup the model with validation.

I have added model binders to connect the request from the form, then sent it to the submit controller for validation.

When the if statement to check if the object binder is correct it sees the code as valid.  Any ideas about what I am doing wrong to check the information in the form using server side validation?

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace messageBoard.Models
{
    public class Messages
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Receiver { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Form { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using messageBoard.Models;

namespace messageBoard.Controllers
{
    public class Messagebinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            HttpContextBase objContext = controllerContext.HttpContext;
            string sender = objContext.Request.Form["txtSender"];
            string reciever = objContext.Request.Form["txtReciever"];
            string form = objContext.Request.Form["txtForm"];

            string strYear = objContext.Request.Form["txtYear"];
            Int32 year = Int32.Parse(strYear);

            string strStart = objContext.Request.Form["txtStartDate"];
            DateTime startParse = DateTime.Parse(strStart);

            string strExpiry = objContext.Request.Form["txtExpiry"];
            DateTime expiryParse = DateTime.Parse(strExpiry);

            string title = objContext.Request.Form["txtTitle"];
            string message = objContext.Request.Form["txtMessage"];

            Messages obj = new Messages()
            {
                Sender = sender,
                Receiver = reciever,
                Form = form,
                Year = year,
                StartDate = startParse,
                Expiry = expiryParse,
                Title =  title,
                Message = message
            };


            return obj;
        }
    }
    public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Messages
        public ActionResult Load()
        {
            Messages obj = new Messages {
                Sender = "Ross McKenzie",
                Receiver = "Noah McKenzie",
                Year = 8,
                Form ="8NM",
                StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 22),
                Expiry = new DateTime(2018, 10, 31),
                Title = "Noah",
                Message = "This is the first message for the test of the internal message board, oh and I love you Noah"

            };
            return View("Messages",obj);
        }
        public ActionResult Enter()
        {
            return View("EnterMessages",new Messages());
        }

        public ActionResult Submit([ModelBinder(typeof(Messagebinder))] Messages obj)
        {

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Messages", obj);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("EnterMessages");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems over-complicated. My suggestion is to let MVC do the work. Use a GET action to get your initial model. Use a POST action with anti-forgery token in the views submit form. If you specify a class as the parameter of the submit action, MVC will load it for you from Model State, assuming there are no client side validation errors - your model strings have a "Required" attribute but can be zero length by the way. If you push server validation into an underlying business model, the controller has nothing much to do (e.g. check data store for duplicate names)

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, are there any links you can give me to read about this.  I'm a novice to MVC and ASP in C# and a lot of what you have said has gone over my head.

Comment: We were all novices once. I'll post some example code. Look at the Microsoft MVC samples and examples - a good place to start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a Controller should be simple and make simple decisions. Here is one of mine from ASP.NET MVC 5

Firstly, I use Dependency injection to pump a business service interface into the constructor. I also use a base class where all controller-common code lives, so I pass the business interface into this which can still be referenced from this class. You'll need to read up on IoC and how to implement it. Microsoft has a simple one that I use but there are others.

```
public SparesSectionsController(IBusinessService bs) : base(bs)
{
}
```

For CRUD operation I have pairs of actions as well as an Index that lists records for CREATE, EDIT, DELETE. Here is one for editing an existing record

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    SparesSection sparesSection = await _bs.SparesSection_GetAsync(id.Value);

    if (sparesSection == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(sparesSection);
}
```

The corresponding POST action binds any required fields as part of the action parameters.

For simplicity, but probably poor practice, I pass model state to the business layer in order that any additional field or general errors can be added. It would be better to define return business layer errors in a separate class defined at the lower level and adding these into Model State. This latter approach breaks dependency on MVC and makes abstracting the business layer for use as a web interface or other independent business source.

Note that ViewMessage is a base class property that simply puts some text into a TempData property. The _Layout then shows the message if it is not null within the view. This approach allows persistence across actions during a redirect, which ViewBag does not

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "SparesSectionId,SparesSectionTitle")] SparesSection sparesSection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _bs.SparesSection_UpdateAsync(sparesSection, ModelState);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewMessage = "Saved " + sparesSection.SparesSectionTitle;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    return View(sparesSection);
}
```

The View is light and compact

```
@model YourProjectName.Models.SparesSection

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Spares Section";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container w-50">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SparesSectionId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SparesSectionTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SparesSectionTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SparesSectionTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="ml-auto">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

As for my model, Because this is a small class, I use the Entity Framework directly and extend it using a partial class. For larger or more complex data I suggest a separate View Model which you populate one get from the EF data, along with any other resources

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#region Spares Section

[MetadataType(typeof(SparesSectionMetaData))]
public partial class SparesSection { }

public class SparesSectionMetaData
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [Required]
    public int SparesSectionId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Spares Section Title")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "2-100 characters")]
    [Required]
    public string SparesSectionTitle { get; set; }
}
```